# A/B test clients from controller

Tags: scala, design-patterns, playframework, playframework-2.6

I am currently using API's from client `A` in my controller. Sample definition of client `A`:

```
class A @Inject()(
    ws: WSClient)
{
  def createSession(request: CreateSessionRequest)
    : EitherT[Future, AppError, ResponseFromA] = 
 {
    //logic. Returns ResponseFromA case class
 }
}
```

My controller code is:

```
class MyController @Inject()(
    a: A) {
  def createSession(): Action[JsValue] =
    action.async(parse.tolerantJson) { request =>
      val requestValidation = for {
        request <- EitherT.fromEither[Future](
          checkRequest[CreateCheckout](request.body.toString, mapper))
      } yield {
        request
      }

      val createSessionResult = for {
        createCheckoutInput <- requestValidation
        createSessionResponse <- a.createSession(
          CreateSessionRequest(createCheckoutInput))
      } yield {
        createSessionResponse
      }

      // postProcessing creates a transfer object `SessionResult`
      // from `ResponseFromA`
      postProcessing(createSessionResult) 
}
```

Now I am planning to migrate to another set of API's which provide similar functionality but different response format. I have created a different client `B` as follows:

```
class B @Inject()(
    ws: WSClient)
{
  def createSession(request: CreateSessionRequest)
    : EitherT[Future, AppError, ResponseFromB] = 
 {
    //logic. Returns ResponseFromB case class
 }
}
```

Notice I have still used `CreateSessionRequest` in client `B` as well. This is because input to both set of API's is the same. I would like to `A/B` test both set of API's. Ideally I would like to use the same controller because controller has a lot of logic which I would need to replicate if I created another controller for client `B`. Response from my controller would also still be `SessionResult` because I want to keep these migration changes transparent to all clients using my service.

I was looking at different design patterns like the [factory pattern](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/factory_pattern.htm) to conditionally select the right client to call based on some rule (say a config value which says to use client `B`) but I am reaching a dead end because `createSession` from both clients have different return values. I was also thinking of creating a common business object which I could use to massage the `ResponseFromA` and 
`ResponseFromB` to the common business object but that means I would need to change `postProcessing(createSessionResult)`.

Any tips or pointers on how I could conditionally use client of my choice without changing controller logic too much would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: can you please check my answer - comment if you still have problems, accept it or share your solution? So it helps others and gives me feedback if my answer are correct or at least help.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to reuse the Controller for both cases, you can:

For Creation: Use a factory, that for example injects both services and then returns the one you have configured.

For Return type: Here you would need a generic Format, I use here `play.api.libs.json.JsValue` sometimes.

If you can reuse `postProcessing` depends on the differences of `ResponseFromA` and `ResponseFromB`